# Video lectures on Generalized Linear Models and Extensions

Tags: multiple-regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, multivariate-analysis, linear-model

I am looking for some video lectures on Generalized Linear Models and Extensions. Also, some good resources that cover "Fundamental theory of model fitting and inference in generalized linear models, analyzing binary and count data in generalized linear models, quasi-likelihood methods, and additional topics as extensions of linear models." I sincerely appreciate your time. Have a good night!

Answer (score 2):

For a video I'd recommend the [MIT 18.650 Statistics for Applications course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-650-statistics-for-applications-fall-2016/index.htm) see lectures 21-24.

Also the Princeton website for their courses on the subject https://data.princeton.edu/wws509

Comment: Thank u so much!